# Zookeeper cli not starting

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper

I've installed zookeeper v 3.4.9 on suse using the following package:

```
http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/nicolasbock:/midokura/openSUSE_Leap_42.2/x86_64/zookeeper-3.4.9-1.1.x86_64.rpm
```

Starting the server works just fine an the various application that need to connect to it seem to be able to do so just fine, however I'm getting a strange error when I try to start the client:

```
zkCli.sh -server 127.0.0.1:2181
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain
```

I've tried searching around the internet but the only answer I've come up with is setting the env variable $CLASSPATH. I tried looking what classpath is used internally by the serve starting script and set $CLASSPATH to that but with no results.

I'm running openjvm v 1.8.0_121

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem today on Ubuntu 18.04. On zookeper [official download page](http://zookeeper.apache.org/releases.html#download) once one follows the given mirror link and chooses stable version, he can see 2 files available. In my case those were:

- `apache-zookeeper-3.5.5-bin.tar.gz`
- `apache-zookeeper-3.5.5.tar.gz`

I chose `apache-zookeeper-3.5.5.tar.gz`, observed the same problem. Tried to print `CLASSPATH` as @Jonathan suggested, it was printing different paths however, problem is that the archive file did not contain zookeper `jar`s, probably it is expected that user packages to `jar` himself as I could find source code in that archive file.

Downloading larger `apache-zookeeper-3.5.5-bin.tar.gz` archive, extracting and running `./zkCli.sh` went smooth as it had everything necessary, so whoever faces the same problem, try that and see if it does the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying on Unix or Windows?

I dont think, you need "-server 127.0.0.1:2181"

Just run zkCli.sh or zkCli.cmd

Comment: I was trying this on linux, opensus 42. Though now I am long past the problem, to be honest I can't remember how I got over it. I do believe I tried starting it without the explicit server parameter to no better results... but I couldn't tell, it was too long ago.

Answer (score 0):

That is a classpath problem. The zkCli.sh script is attempting to launch a java app where the main class is ZooKeeperMain. However, java cannot find the ZooKeeperMain class file because the classpath being passed to java does not contain a jar file that contains the ZooKeeperMain class.

Typically, the ZooKeeperMain.class file is contained in a jar file at something like `$ZOOKEEPER_HOME/zookeeper-3.4.13.jar`.

You might trying modifying the zkCli.sh script to print out the classpath just before the script attempts to launch ZooKeeperMain. The classpath should contain the jar that contains the ZooKeeperMain class.

On my Windows 10 machine, my classpath looks like this:

`/c/Program Files (x86)/Zookeeper/bin/../build/classes:/c/Program Files (x86)/Zookeeper/bin/../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar:/c/Program Files (x86)/Zookeeper/bin/../lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/c/Program Files (x86)/Zookeeper/bin/../lib/netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:/c/Program Files (x86)/Zookeeper/bin/../lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/c/Program Files (x86)/Zookeeper/bin/../lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/c/Program Files (x86)/Zookeeper/bin/../lib/audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar:/c/Program Files (x86)/Zookeeper/bin/../zookeeper-3.4.12.jar:/c/Program Files (x86)/Zookeeper/bin/../conf:`

I encountered a similar errors as yours when launching zkCli.sh from Git Bash for Windows on my Windows 10 machine. My issue was because of the way Git Bash was handling wildcards in the classpath. I initially had some `*.jar` entries in my classpath that I removed to get zkCli.sh to launch.